# Proper way to update CALayer's model layer with a delayed CABasicAnimation

Tags: ios, caanimation

I have a layer on which I define an animation with a `beginTime` in the future (`CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.3`). In order to synchronize the model layer with the presentation layer I usually set the final property value (a `path` in this case) right before I start the animation. In this case however, this will cause the final animation value to be displayed until the property animation starts.

The only way I can think of fixing this right now is with a delegate, but this seems ugly and convoluted. Is there a recommended way to do this?

Comment: Set the layer's `fillMode` to `backwards`? Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: I may be doing something wrong, but that doesn't appear to work unfortunately. Right now I actually added a "filler" animation in the empty gap before it starts that just keeps the values constant - which is arguably even uglier than the delegate.

Comment: Actually, scratch that, I've been at this too long and did something wrong. At least for the one animation which is part of an animation group this *does* work. I'm gonna check out the other one shortly (or tomorrow if I fall asleep).

Comment: Ok for the other one it also works; though now my timing is broken, but that's a different problem. As far as this question goes though - if you write this as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try setting the layer's `fillMode` to `.backwards`.